# How to make a duplicate check on existing records?

Tags: duplicate-management

My requirement is to build a visualforce page with a controller, where i can show the user the records that are matched by a duplicate rule, for this i would like to know if it is possible to invoke a method of the duplicate rule itself to return the records without forcing an insert/update on the record that i want to find duplicates of. I can not find any method like this, so i was thinking about using the MatchingRuleItem, and build a query based on those fields. Is this the correct way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce Duplicate Management works based on create or edit operation.

You could get [DuplicateRule](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_duplicaterule.htm) which helps for detecting duplicate records for an SObjectType.

And you could get [DuplicateResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_duplicateresult.htm#sforce_api_objects_duplicateresult)

> Represents the details of a duplicate rule that detected duplicate records and information about those duplicate records.

But, salesforce didn't expose any kind of API which you are searching for your use case.